# Invertible Matrices Proof

Tags: matrices

Given that B is an invertible matrix and $B^3 + B^4 + B^7 = I$, find an expression for $B^{-1}$ in terms of only $B$. (where $I$ is an identity matrix)

$B$ is a matrix that is $n \times n$.

Comment: Common factor may help?

Comment: $B ( B^2+B^3+B^6) = I$.

Comment: You know that $B$ is invertible, because if $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, then the above  shows that $(\lambda^3+\lambda^4+\lambda^7) v = v$, hence $\lambda \neq 0$.

Comment: First of all, if $m\neq n$ then $B^3+B^4+B^7$ doesn't make sense - you can't compute $B^k$ without $m=n$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Also $B$ being invertible implies it is square.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to assume $B$ is invertible. Indeed

$$B^3+B^4+B^7=B(B^2+B^3+B^6)=I\implies B^{-1}=B^2+B^3+B^6.$$